# max_execution_time in PHP

Tags: php, parameters, execution, execution-time

Let's assume max_execution_time is set to 30 seconds.

Let's assume there is a script, **long.php**, that takes a very long time to execute (more than 30 seconds).

Let's aslo that **long.php** contains this line of code: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);` and let's further assume that the aforementioned line of code gets executed after 20 seconds of starting **long.php**.

Now my question is, does the above line of code make max execution time 60 seconds (max time since the start of the script) or 80 seconds (20 seconds from the start, then calculated  `max_execution_time` since the change)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't go over your hoster's default time limit.

Comment: i think that is the whole time

Comment: This is something you could trivially test yourself...

Comment: @MarcB Or I could ask on Stack Overflow and benefit the community

Comment: benefiting the community would be YOU doing the test, and then reporting on the results. Right now you're just wanting someone else to do what you could have discovered with a few lines of code and 5 minutes' time.

Comment: @MarcB Easy tiger! We have different views on how to do things. No need to be angry. What you said exactly happened: someone reported the result and benefitted the community because of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about using `ini_set`, but [`set_time_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) will reset the counter, so you'll end up with 80s.

> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero.